# Display the last or first name of the user who has logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to display user fist name when they log in to the application?

This comes with mvc template, however I would like to customize this base on user name not user ID.

```
  Hello , @Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.Name, "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "username", title = "Manage" })!
```

Comment: Where does the user's name come from?

Comment: from system.security.prinicipla.Iprincipla which is built in in MVC

Comment: `User.Identity.Name` is indeed the user ID, not the user's (first) name. I believe wat @CraigW. was asking is: where do you intend to get the user's first name from?

Comment: my database, when they login to the app it associates with their ID and populate their first name

Answer (score 1):

Given that you need to pull the user's name from the database you'll need to make it available to the view in some fashion. Options include:

1. Adding it to Session.
2. Putting it into ViewData/ViewBag
3. Adding it to the ViewModel

Without knowing more detail about how your application is structured, how the views and controllers are set up, whether this is something you want on every page or just one page, it's hard to say which of these is the best option.

Comment: Don't forget using a cookie.  This is the technique many sites use.  You notice that when you come back to a site, it remembers your name, but when you try to do anything it requires you to log in... that's because the username was saved in a cookie.

Comment: There are some problems I see with using a cookie, which is why I didn't mention it. (1) It's stored on the client side which means it is susceptible to manipulation (unless you encrypt it); (2) You're schlepping that data back and forth across the network on every request; (4) EU rules around cookies, requiring users to opt out of them, and disclosing their use makes it a big PITA. As a result of those reasons I like to minimize cookie use to only those that I can't solve the problem any other way.

Comment: Who cares if someone manipulates the display name of the user?  If you really care, you can encrypt it as you mention.  I don't think 20 bytes of data is a huge amount to schlep around.  I think the EU rules apply to cross site and tracking cookies.  Virtually every .net website has several cookies, and nobody I know in the EU discloses them.

Comment: I care because once it's there I don't know what another developer might decide to use that data for, and it now becomes untrusted data because it's coming from the client. Here's an article to help you understand the EU requirements (hint, it goes beyond tracking cookies). http://www.computerweekly.com/opinion/The-new-EU-cookie-rule-so-we-need-to-get-consent-then